# Where to close connection/file/logs with multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Assume the following pseudo code for a simple two thread scenario:

I have two threads, I would like to insert data to different tables to database. On thread1, I would like to insert to some table, at same time, I want to insert other data to thread 2. **My question is how/where to place connection.close(),** if I place it on thread 1 and it executes while thread2 is still processing, or vice versa, if thread2 has finished and closed the connection, yet thread1 hasn't finished.

Note, the database is just an example, it can be anything like a file,logger..etc.

```
class Thread1{
    DataBaseConnection connection;
    main(){
        threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        connection.open();
        if(ThisMightTakeSomeTime)
        threadPool.submit(new MyRunnable(connection));
        InsertDataToDataBase(Table A, Table B));
        connection.Close(); //What if thread2 isn't done yet?
    }
}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    MyRunnable(connection){}
    @override
    void Run() { ...}
    void TaskThatMayTakeWhile(){
        ...get data ...
        ...Connection.InsertToTables(table X, table Y)
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't read all the way through the code, but why aren't you using two different database connections from a pool? Just close the one when it's finished and the other will close when it is done?

Comment: The threads should run in the same transaction (single commit)?

Comment: Thread.join in thread1 on thread2 or use a Latch (java.util.cocurrent.CountdownLatch) initialized in thread 1 an released by thread 2?

Comment: @robermann, No, I meant I need to be able to be writing to the database concurrently from two different threads, different commits.

Comment: @D-Koltz, the Database was just an example, in my actual code, this is actually an Indexer instance for a search engine like a Solr.

Comment: Are you sure that 'Solr' is thread safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is how/where to place connection.close(),

To start, as far as I know, you should *not* be sharing a single connection with 2 different threads.  Each thread should have it's own database connection, possibly utilizing a database connection pool such as [Apache's DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/).

Once you have multiple connections, I would have each thread manage and release its own connection back to the pool.  You should make sure this is done in a `finally` block to make sure that if there is a database exception, the connection is still released.

If you are forced to have multiple threads share the same connection then they will have to use `synchronized` to make sure they have an exclusive lock to it:

```
 synchronized (connection) {
    // use the connection
 }
```

As to when to close it if it is shared, you could have a shared usage counter (maybe an `AtomicInteger`) and close it when the counter goes to 0.  Or as others have recommended you could use a thread-pool and then the thread pool is done free the connection.

> Note, the database is just an example, it can be anything like a file,logger..etc.

In terms of a more generic answer I always try to mirror where the thing is created.  If a method opens the stream then it should have the `finally` that closes the stream.

```
 public void someMethod() {
    InputStream stream = ...
    try {
         // process the stream here probably by calling other methods
    } finally {
         // stream should be closed in the same method for parity
         stream.close();
    }
 }
```

The exception to this pattern is a thread handler.  Then the `Thread` should close the stream or release connection in a `finally` block at the end of the `run()` or `call()` method.

```
 public void serverLoopMethod() {
     while (weAcceptConnections) {
        Connection connection = accept(...);
        threadPool.submit(new ConnectionHandler(connection);
     }
 }
 ...
 private static class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
     private Connection connection;
     public ConnectionHandler(Connection connection) {
         this.connection = connection;
     }
     // run (or call) method executed in another thread
     public void run() {
         try {
            // work with the connection probably by calling other methods
         } finally {
              // connection is closed at the end of the thread run method
              connection.close();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answers. I used the database as an example to make it simple, What if the connection is a singleton instance and I can't create another?

Comment: Then you are going to have to `synchronized` lock on it in each thread @user1529412 when you use it.  As to when to close it you could have a shared usage counter (maybe `AtomicInteger`) and close it when the counter goes to 0.  Or as others have recommended you could use a thread-pool and then the thread pool is done free the connection.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your code it's likely that database connection will be closed before `insert` statement execution and of course `insert` will be unsuccessful.

**Proper solutions**
If you have **multiple insert tasks**:

1. Use `ExecutorService` instead of `Execuutor`
2. Submit all tasks
3. Invoke `executorService.shutdown()` it will wait until all submitted tasks are done.
4. Close connection

If you have **only one task** to submit:
You should close the connection after `Connection.InsertToTables(table X, table Y)` in your task.

Good for **both scenarios** and recommended:
Each tasks has it own `connection`.

Example:

```
class Thread1 {
        private static DataSource dataSource; // initialize it

        public static void main(String[] args){
            ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            threadPool.submit(new MyRunnable(dataSource));                
        }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private final DataSource dataSource;

    MyRunnable(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void run() {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        // do something with connection
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I chose Gray's answer as the correct one because it goes a bit more in depth, even though your answer is also correct. I upvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Thread1{
    DataBaseConnection connection;
    main(){
        threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        connection.open();
        if(ThisMightTakeSomeTime)
        Future f = threadPool.submit(new MyRunnable(connection));
        InsertDataToDataBase(Table A, Table B));
        f.get(); // this will hold the program until the Thread finishes.
        connection.Close(); //What if thread2 isn't done yet?
    }
}
```

the Future is the reference resulting from the submit call. if we call Future.get(), that will block the current thread until the submited thread finishes.